# "wake up BY alarm clock" vs "wake up FROM alarm clock"

Tags: prepositions

"wake up BY alarm clock" vs "wake up FROM alarm clock"
What's the difference? What's more correct?

Comment: Wake up from or by the **ringing** of an alarm clock.

Comment: I am/was **awoken** by an alarm clock.

Comment: I woke up when the alarm clock rang. I wake up when the alarm clock rings. *The alarm clock on its own does not actually wake you*. However, you can be awoken by your family members.

Comment: You are woken **from** sleep **by** the alarm clock!

Comment: @Kate Bunting, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"By" but not in that form.

You can use a passive voice sentence:

> I was woken up by my alarm clock.

or active

> My alarm clock woke me up.