# "wake up BY alarm clock" vs "wake up FROM alarm clock"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

"wake up BY alarm clock" vs "wake up FROM alarm clock"
What's the difference? What's more correct?

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: This is a dup. Voting to close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["wake up BY alarm clock" vs "wake up FROM alarm clock"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292142/wake-up-by-alarm-clock-vs-wake-up-from-alarm-clock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither are idiomatic. I would say "I woke up **to** my alarm clock." Note that you need some kind of determiner before "alarm clock," whether an article like *the* or *an* or a possessive like *my* or *your*.